# Sitecore Comparing HTML elements in WebForm and WebPage

Tags: razor, webforms, sitecore

I have a placeholder named "content".

`<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch" />`

- **In Sublayout item (WebForm)**, I added a simple above checkbox element in sublayout.ascx file, then added this sublayout component onto the placeholder in content page.
  I can toggle the check and uncheck by clicking.
- **In Rendering Item (View Rendering)**, I added the same checkbox element in rendering.cshtml, then added this View rendering component onto the placeholder in content page. I CAN'T toggle the check and uncheck by clicking.

If I view the source of the page using WebForm, I could see `<code>` element with defined datasource information underneath checkbox input element. But, ViewRendering is not.

Why?????

How can I make the rendering page as WebForm does??

**From .ascx layout (View Source of Page)**

```
<input name="main_0$centercolumn_0$ch" type="checkbox" id="main_0_centercolumn_0_ch">
<code type="text/sitecore" chrometype="placeholder" kind="open" id="_main_centercolumn_content" key="/main/centercolumn/content" class="scpm" data-selectable="true">
    {"commands":
        [{
            "click":"chrome:placeholder:addControl",
            "header":"Add to here",
            "icon":"/temp/IconCache/Applications/16x16/add2.png",
            "disabledIcon":"/temp/add2_disabled16x16.png",
            "isDivider":false,
            "tooltip":"Add a new rendering to the '{0}' placeholder.","type":""
        },
        {
            "click":"chrome:placeholder:editSettings",
            "header":"",
            "icon":"/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Custom/16x16/edit_placeholder_pageeditor.png",
            "disabledIcon":"/temp/edit_placeholder_pageeditor_disabled16x16.png",
            "isDivider":false,
            "tooltip":"Edit the placeholder settings.","type":""
        }],
        "contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{419180A8-2B07-4C92-9880-A01CB2FCE235}?lang=en&amp;ver=8",
        "custom":{"allowedRenderings":[
                                        "493B3A830FA744848FC94680991CF743",
                                        "4E428A766D214C9BB4EFDBB3943565F0",
                                        "D5A2772AC14A4AB28E9116B59DEE2B34",
                                        "28F99AEC25BA4611A8BF39274C69C1C4",
                                        "E6E21E7286824773ABBC7B746B0E2A59",
                                        "A34CA1A819324408B07BBC1625A4AAB7",
                                        "B2868099F18644A78123BF0D18AC0139",
                                        "30ED63BC1C5A48E9A0212E0836B3E69F",
                                        "6A54B0C5552149D28B32CF71F9745935",
                                        "561B3FFB3EE649AA9570E828D65E919E"
                                        ],
        "editable":"true"
        },
        "displayName":"content",
        "expandedDisplayName":null
    }
</code>
```

**From Razor layout (View Source of Page)**

```
<input name="ch" type="checkbox" id="ch">
```

Comment: As they are native HTML checkboxes they should be exactly the same. Why have you got a <code> tag in your markup? Is there any JavaScript affecting the checkbox elements? Can you post some more of your razor view?

Comment: Are you adding the view rendering into the same layout as the ascx? You can't mix and match in the same request, so you need to make sure your layout file is also razor.

Comment: @jammykam Of course, I have two layouts (one is for .ascx and the other one is for .cshtml)

Comment: @IanGraham I also tried to add Html.Helper like `@Html.Checkbox("chID")`. The output has the same issue. I could manually add the `<code>` tag with defined placeholder key and something else, but I want to know WHY??? and there should be a solution than manually adding the <code> tag.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using? Are you sure [MVC is enabled](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/06/sitecore-mvc-playground-part-1-enable-mvc.aspx) on your site?

Comment: @jammykam Yes, everything is working well in MVC with razor layout and rendering components too. The problem is only in `<input type="checkbox" ... />`

Comment: @jammykam I'm using Sitecore 7.0

Comment: Well the `<code>` blocks have nothing to do with the checkbox, it is output by Sitecore for the placeholder to allow you to add additional renderings. Try in Preview mode if the checkbox is working.

Comment: @jammykam In Preview mode, it works. In Editor mode, it is not working.